# Can Data.Vector's modify ever really be done in place?

Tags: haskell, haskell-vector

In the source for `modify` it [is stated](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.2/docs/src/Data.Vector.Generic.html#modify) that the operation will be performed in place if it is safe to do so and will modify a copy of the vector otherwise.

But looking at the code for `modify`:

```
modify :: Vector v a => (forall s. Mutable v s a -> ST s ()) -> v a -> v a
modify p = new . New.modify p . clone
```

It looks to me that `clone` is always called (which makes sense to me, as I would think it would have to be for a destructive operation on an immutable vector).

Am I misunderstanding this? If not, what is an example of where `clone` is not called, and how does `Data.Vector` accomplish the bypass?

Comment: Maybe the compiler can optimise this away?

Comment: Sorry, thought I had searched for this late the other night when I was wondering about it - but apparently didn't search well enough! This will take some time to digest but I'm confident it answers my question. If not, I'll ask a more specific question.

Comment: no need to apologize, I only knew of the other question because I had answered.  It's a great question.